# BibTeX Error: White space in argument

Tags: bibtex

I am running LaTeX on a Mac and am getting the following error message when I run BibTeX:

```
White space in argument---line 19 of file file.aux
 : \bibdata{\protect
 :                   \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}/Documents/University/references}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this without any code that shows what you are doing.  Try to comment out parts of your document until the error disappears and then you can maybe identify the problem.  If you're still stuck you can then post a minimal document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Looks as if you are using a `~` (`\nobreakspace`)) in the file name. Try `\string~` instead (but I have no idea if bibtex will like it).

Comment: At least on Mac OS X, `\bibliography{\string~/Documents/references}` works.

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: I think I have a different problem now because the tek log file is saying "No bbl found"